# pst-pdgr package import error

Tags: pstricks

I am getting following error just by importing pst-pdgr package.

```
`PSTricks' v2.77  <2017/10/04> (tvz)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2805 \ifpst@psfonts
```

It was working fine few days earlier. Any ideas?

Thanks

Update:

I get an answer from the author of the package. He says that last pstricks update caused backward compability problems. pst-pdgr package from CTAN works without a problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimal, but compilable example to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Insert into your document before the first PSTricks related package
(I suppose it is `pst-pdgr`):

```
 \usepackage{pstricks}
```

Comment: I updated the main post.

Comment: The above line was missing in `pst-pdgr.sty`!